AnyLogic split output after merging them into one delay
In need help with anylogic. I have several source lines that produce different materials but eventually meet in one delay function to get painted. I can't figure out how to separate them to their initial values in order to add another delay.
Tried with selectouput in and out, but it only allows set the percentage how they will be divided.
Tried adding a function to separate them by given parameters as they were colors. Only worked with one source, but not with several sources. Currently I have the same agent type for all, but I also tried creating different agents, but wasn't successful.
I was suggested to create a database to run all materials within one source, but don't know how to make it yet. If anyone has a suggestion would highly appreciate

UPDATE: Followed the suggestion in the comments, currently got this error, couldn't debug. Please help
![]anylogic.selesctoutput]2

It depends on the setup. Do your sources create different agent types or the same agent type but varying something inside the agent type? Or is it all the same? Add some screens to help us help you, if possible

Ok, still not quite clear how you distinguish agents. But assuming:

all these sources create the same agent type
sources vary 1 characteristic only, say a variable in the agent type of type String named myDiff

then you can simply distinguish them using
agent.myDiff.equals(...) in a SelectOutput condition
Since you seem to have a ton of different conditions, you likely need to write a separate function, but that is a different matter
PS: pro-tip: build tiny simple example models to try get something like this to work conceptually first. Then, implement in such a big and complicated model step-by-step. Try my tip above with 2 sources, 1 delay and 1 SelectOutput first. Then, in baby-steps, expand to what you have

Thank you so much! Still didn't get what goes inside the parenthesis. If possible could you please share an example here or to my email, will highly appreciate maksutovn@g.cofc.edu, thanks again

Well, time to get to the basics then, tbh. No time to send tailored examples, sorry. Feel free to ask tiny specific questions anytime. StackOverflow is a Q&A place, not a forum. So learn how to ask good questions and you get your problems solved in no time: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow

(best questions can be answered with 1 word, 2nd-best with 1 sentence. Anything beyond that has diminishing chances of replies :) )

Good to know that, I will keep in mind for the next time, thank you. I have followed your suggestion, still getting errors, if you could follow it up, I have updated screenshot in the post. Thank you!

always open new issues, describing everything from scratch. This helps build a knowledge base. And again: SOF is not a forum (where you go deeper and deeper into an issue). It is Q&A: short question, short answer. Use it to your advantage as you have a higher chance to get complex issues resolved by splitting it into tiny issues.
